# How do we conclude using De Morgan's laws that these two are equal?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Question: (p∧q)→(p∨q)≡¬(p∧q)∨(p∨q)

Which steps should I take to derive the equation to the right from the equation to the left? In the book, it just shows this equation but doesn't answer how did they actually get it. Since this example in the book shows up under the De Morgan's laws section, I rightfully considered De Morgan's laws could help us to solve this problem.

If you need the full question just tell me.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I mean, let's forget about the right side of the equation. I just wonder how one could prove (p∧q)→(p∨q) is equal to (p∧q)∨(p∨q). That is, you haven't been given the right side of the equation when you began.

Comment: Hi & welcome to MSE!We hope you have a great learning experience here!We suggest you to use $\LaTeX$ to format your question body to ensure your posts are better received!!

Comment: LHS: apply [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) to remove $\to$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the definition of $a\rightarrow b$: it is 
$$(\lnot a)\vee b$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall:  In general, $A \to B$ is equivalent to $B \lor \lnot A$.

So then in this case, $\underbrace{(p \land q)}_A \to \underbrace{(p \lor q)}_B$ is equivalent to $\underbrace{(p \lor q)}_B \lor \underbrace{\lnot (p \land q)}_{\lnot A}$

Didn't realize when I started that that was basically it..  The conclusion in the book is the same since it doesn't matter which one comes first when you use $\lor.\quad$  $B \lor \lnot A$ is the same as $\lnot A \lor B$.

Comment: Many thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a truth-table:

\begin{array}{cc|ccc|cccccc}
p & q & (p \land q) & \rightarrow & (p \lor q) & \neg & (p \land q) & \lor & (p \lor q)\\
\hline
T & T & T & \color{red}T & T & F & T & \color{red}T & T\\
T & F & F & \color{red}T & T & T & F & \color{red}T & T\\
F & T & F & \color{red}T & T & T & F & \color{red}T & T\\
F & F & F & \color{red}T & F & T & F & \color{red}T & F
\end{array}

We see that the two statementrs have the same truth-conditions (in fact, it turns out they are both tautologies), so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If both $p$ and $q$ are true, then at least one of either $p$ or $q$ will be true.

> Since this example in the book shows up under the De Morgan's laws section, I rightfully considered De Morgan's laws could help us to solve this problem.

Yes, but it is too soon.   The step you have applies Material Implication.

- $\qquad(p\wedge q)\to (p\vee q)~~\equiv~~\neg (p\wedge q)\vee (p\vee q)$

This sets it up to apply deMorgan's Rule *next*.

- $\qquad\phantom{(p\wedge q)\to (p\vee q)} ~~\equiv~~(\neg p\vee \neg q)\vee (p\vee q)$

Finish with association and commutation, contradiction, and then annihlation.

- $\qquad\phantom{(p\wedge q)\to (p\vee q)}~~\equiv~~\top$